# Trimming a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have an `std::vector` of `std::strings` containing data similar to this:

```
[0] = ""
[1] = "Abc"
[2] = "Def"
[3] = ""
[4] = "Ghi"
[5] = ""
[6] = ""
```

How can I get a vector containing the 4 strings from 1 to 4? (i.e. I want to trim all blank strings from the start and end of the vector):

```
[0] = "Abc"
[1] = "Def"
[2] = ""
[3] = "Ghi"
```

Currently, I am using a forward iterator to make my way up to `"Abc"` and a reverse iterator to make my way back to `"Ghi"`, and then constructing a new vector using those iterators. This method works, but I want to know if there is an easier way to trim these elements.

P.S. I'm a C++ noob.

#### Edit

Also, I should mention that the vector may be composed entirely of blank strings, in which case a 0-sized vector would be the desired result.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the iterators until I got to your last paragraph. What you're currently doing does sound like the C++ way.

Comment: You can use std::find_if to avoid having to write the loops. (But note that this prevents you from doing simultaneous iteration from end and beginning to detect that a lengthy vector is composed of empty strings only)

Comment: @villintehaspam: What's the point of doing it from simultaneously? You need to check all elements when it's empty. Might as well do it in the find_if..

Comment: @dreamlax: What's your compiler? This is exactly the kind of stuff that becomes a lot easier with lambdas..

Comment: @Itjax: Yeah, just my imagination going a bit wild there I believe. As long as one checks the result from the first search before doing the reverse the above shouldn't apply. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ltjax: I'm using the C++ compiler that comes with the Win7 DDK.

Comment: That should be the Visual Studio 2010 compiler, so you can also use std::find_if like `std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& s) {return !s.empty();});` which is a lot neater.

Comment: @ltjax: But that will strip out the blank line in the middle too. I just want to trim them from the beginning and end. Similar to how `trimstr("The quick brown fox     ")` would not give you `"Thequickbrownfox"`.

Comment: My solution won't (or at least that's not how I intended it). It just scans to the first non-empty string from the end, removes all those, and once from the beginning and removes all those. It'll never reach those in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this, with a predicate:

```
class StringNotEmpty
{
  bool operator()(const std::string& s) { return !s.empty(); }
};
```

Now to trim:

```
vec.erase(std::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), StringNotEmpty()).base(), vec.end());
vec.erase(vec.begin(), std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), StringNotEmpty()));
```

There might be an off-by-one on the `.base()` call, but the general idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is reasonable. Another approach is to find the first string, and then copy all successive strings to the beginning (and following) elements in the vector, after which you trim the end of the vector.

Unless this is a critical piece of code that is slowing down your application, it matters more that it works than that you have the most efficient implementation possible.

Comment: Yeah I'm not at all concerned with performance, I just want the approach that easiest to understand. I'm looking at my iterator approach and thinking that I probably won't remember why it works in a year's time (it just *seems* messy).

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is good.  But if you want to shorten a single container "in place" rather than make a copy of a subrange, you can `erase` the other ranges from the `vector`.

```
// Probably similar to what you already have: Find iterators for the range to keep.
std::vector<std::string>::iterator start=strs.begin(), stop=strs.end();
start = strs.begin();

while (start != stop && start->empty()) ++start;
if (start == stop) {
  // all strings were empty!
  strs.clear();
} else {
  while (start != --stop && stop->empty()) ;
  ++stop;

  // std::vector<std::string>(start, stop) is the desired subrange
  strs.erase(stop, strs.end());
  strs.erase(strs.begin(), start);
}
```

But I agree with @Nathan: If you what you already have makes more sense to you than this, keep it, unless you know or strongly suspect that there will be an awful lot of strings involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::vector<std::strings> Strings;

Strings myStrings;
//... currently myStrings contains "","Abc","Def","","Ghi","",""

Strings::iterator itNewBegin = myStrings.begin();
Strings::iterator itNewEnd = myStrings.end();

std::advance(itNewBegin,1);
std::advance(itNewEnd,4);

String myTrimmedStrings(itNewBegin,itNewEnd);
//... currently myTrimmedStringscontains "Abc","Def","","Ghi"
```

By curiosity, I would like to see your code with the use of the reverse iterator.
I don't grasp the way you contruct new vector from two iterators that have different directions.

Comment: I use the `.base()` member of the reverse iterator to turn it back into a forwards iterator.

Comment: oh thanx, it's been long I'm no longer playing back and forth between forward and reverse iterators, too much headache for me. In my code I have shown you the use of the function td::advance, it is sometimes useful. There is its counterpart std::distance that tells you the current position of the iterator in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are definitely the way to go. They make the code much more readable and intuitive.

```
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<std::string> strVec_t;

bool notEmpty(std::string s){
  return !s.empty();
}

void trim(strVec_t& vec){

  //get the first and last non-empty elements
  strVec_t::const_iterator        first = std::find_if(vec.begin(),  vec.end(),  notEmpty);
  strVec_t::const_reverse_iterator last = std::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), notEmpty);

  //if every element is an empty string, delete them all
  if (first == vec.end()){
    vec.clear();

  //make a new vector from the first to the last non-empty elements
  } else {
    vec = strVec_t(first, last.base());
  }
}
```